# StockTwit User Lookup

Tags: c#, stocktwits

I am using the ST Search/User API method and am able to get a response however it is limited. In the documentation found [here](https://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#search-users-docs), if you click on "Extended Version" it shows you can get the followers, following, ideas, and etc. However when I access the API, I only get in return id, type, username, name, avatar. Its very limited compared to the API documentation.

Am I doing something wrong or has the API changed? The query I am using is this `https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/search/users.json?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&q=USERNAME`

Comment: I found another way to get this information, directly scrape it from the user's profile using HAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended data is for partner level access only. Please refer to the getting started guide here https://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/start

If you would like partner level access, please send us an email at api@stocktwits.com